# How to retrieve values from a dynamically generated html form field

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I have a form that was generated from a form builder. I have succeeded in getting the generated form into a shortcode and displayed on the front end. My difficulty now is to retrieve the values from the generated form when its filled on the front end. Below is my code:

```
 function shortcode_form(){
      global $wpdb;
 $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'contactform';

 $queri = "SELECT * FROM $table_name";
 $query = $wpdb->get_results($queri);
// var_dump($query);

foreach($query as $info){
      
    $form_name = $info->form_name;
  $email = $info->email;

   $subject = $info->subject;
    
   $sender = $info->sender;

   $message = $info->message;

    $other_email = $info->other_email;

    $form_content = $info->form_content;
    }

      //send form data to email

     if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    
      // sanitize form values
    $name    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["field1"] );
    $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["field3"] );
    $subject =  sanitize_text_field($_POST["field4"]);
    $message    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["field5"] );
    $to = $get_mailinfo['email'];
    $subject = $get_mailinfo['subject'];
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject    \n\nMessage: $message";
    $headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$to.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' .                                    $email;
    
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

}

 $content.='<form method="POST" action="" class="form-horizontal">';

 $content.=$form_content;     
 
 $content.='</form>';

 return $content;

}
```

and displays from here in a shortcode

How do i retrieve the values when this form is filled. The fields are named

```
name="text[]" //for text type field
name="email[]" //for email type field
```

I'd like to be able to get the values and the label from the form to send by email using PHP

Comment: can you put some code here so we can help? e.g php script with the form?

Comment: @Mostav i have edited the code. Please have a look